# The Role of Data in openCPU

Tags: r, opencpu

I am well aware of the fact, that this might not be the typical SO question, but since this is the strongest R programming community I know and the author of opencpu [explicitly encourages to post here](http://public.opencpu.org/pages/faq.html), I'll give it a try:

What role does data play in the `opencpu` approach? I mean cloud computing is nice, but you need some data to calculate. Uploading some example .csv or .xls table might be straight forward, but what does opencpu have in mind for real world data?

What about several hundred MBs (or even GBs) of data? How would you a) transfer it to your user folder? How would you b) share it among a group of authenticated users and c) hide it from the public?

I read the [license](http://public.opencpu.org/pages/license.html) part and from what I understand for safety it should be possible to run the calculations behind the scene as long as the source code is publicly available. But still, the little document leaves open questions and lot of guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for trying OpenCPU. OpenCPU is still an evolving project at this point, so we are open to interesting suggestions or use cases.

About the data... you are asking many things at once. Some thoughts:

- At this point, OpenCPU does not solve the 'big data' problem. It does not scale beyond what R itself scales to. It is mostly meant as an infrastructure for small to medium sized data; e.g. a typical research paper, project, etc.
- OpenCPU is an API. It is not limited to browser clients. It is designed to be called from other clients as well.
- OpenCPU has a store that you use to store R objects on the server. E.g you upload a CSV or whatever once, and then you store the actual dataframe. In any subsequent calls you can then include this object as an argument to function calls.
- Another approach would be to combine it with a external database (e.g. mysql) and dynamically pull the data in your R code (e.g. using RMySQL)
- Afaik, the legal aspects of open data are not completely clear at this point. I don't think there is consensus on how copyright applies to data, and what a good license would be.  However, a key feature in the design of OpenCPU is making sure things are easily reproducible. This can of course only be done when the data is actually public.

Comment: copyright might not be the only issue w.r.t. data. For us is rather privacy issues on the micro level since we use a lot survey data. Thanks for your answers, particularly the second one is a good reminder. Just related your work to the web too much obviously..

Comment: Jeroen, Thanks for OpenCPU -- it's a fantastic platform. Just a question -- You mentioned possibly integrating OpenCPU with a database. Is there anyone working on this? I would like to do this, if not -- do you have any specific ideas in mind how to approach this?

Comment: @tooringtest There already are R packages that deal with databases, Jeroen mentioned RMySQL, there's also RODBC, ROracle etc. Basically you can send a script to openCPU which connects to your DB, and then processes and graphs its contents. I think it's not any more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

I'm dealing with a real-life use case that involves transforming and processing data from a 3GB (but growing) dataset. Here is the approach I am using (mostly based on suggestions from [Gergely Daróczi](https://disqus.com/home/user/twitter-718673564)):

- as long as the source data can fit into the server memory, I'd choose to load the data with my R package and persist that data across user sessions (e.g. preloading data packages with OpenCPU)
- if that's not option on your server, an alternative is to copy your data to Ramdisk (Linux tmpfs system) into `.rds` (or `.rda`, `.rData`, etc.) files and set these paths using `getOption("path_to_my_persistent_data_files")` in your R package, then load/unload these file(s) as needed in your package functions
- when your data no longer fits into memory, I'd look into using a MongoDB backend together with R interface [rmongodb](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html), as that would likely be faster and easier to maintain than an RDBMS.

Currently OpenCPU does not provide any support for large persistent datasets, it's up to you to find an approach that best suits your needs and resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a local instance of opencpu. You don't have to use the existing one on the Internet. Instructions are on the site.

Comment: Yup, I downloaded that installation guides and have read previous working paper's from Jeroen. Yet it remains unclear what the standard idea / role of data is. Would you want to transfer a 1 GB dataset via a web browser. I wanted to know whether there's a standard way, respectively what the recommendation of the author might be. NAS-drive ? ssh?